# ASP.NET Core SignalR IHubContext<>.Clients.All.SendAsync await more than 5 minutes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asynchronous, signalr

Hub function:

```
public async Task SendBatchingPoll(string Token, double TimerSeconds)
{
    await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveBatchingPoll", Token, TimerSeconds);
}
```

Server-side async await code:

```
await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveBatchingPoll", Token, TimerSeconds);
```

I wanted to send a SignalR message from server-side to client-side and it used to work fine, but recently I noticed that service-side await `_hubContext` most times take more than 5 minutes get to the next line of code but Client Side receive the message within seconds. I was wondering why this delay happens and is it a good idea to remove the await tag from Server Side when we sending SignalR message from Server Side to Client Side

Comment: How long will take if you remove the await?

Comment: It just goes instantly but I saw some post about the SignalR will fail if we remove the await

Comment: Based on your description, this problem looks like a thread starvation problem, we need more code to judge where there is an encoding problem. So pls provide more code about `_hubContext`, if it possible, you can share your signalr code for us.(Hide your sensitive info)

Comment: @JasonPan I'm using it in many devices (Android, Windows Service, JQuery) because I have chat system, real-time GPS system and some real-time data sharing connected to it and it worked fined until like 2 weeks ago. I've hosted this in AWS Elastic Beanstalk. The example I put is a simple data sharing with the Windows Service connecting it to an API. So, when I request the API, Windows Service get the SignalR message instantly but the API response take like 5-8 minutes to complete because I've put the await tag in _hubContext.Clients.All

Comment: For these kind of issues, you should let your experience developer to capture the dumps, then analysis. We don't know the reason in this issue.

Comment: All we can do in application side, just enable the asp.net core server side logs and client side logs. But I don't think it colud help us to find out the cause.

Comment: @JasonPan The solve for this was very weird though. I has several methods on my Controllers which was async void Function(). I just changed all of the async void Functions to async Task Functions and await those whenever those got called. After that SignalR Hubs worked without any delays. I can't even find a reason why that happened too.

Comment: Did you fix it ? I have same problem. My all hub functions are working but only one function is responding 5 - 10 minutes and i cant fix it. I create an action in my api controller and I used same codes and it works. I cant find the problem.

Comment: @Mcan_Cicek What I did two things to fix the issue.

1. I had several async void functions which I was running inside some SignalR Hubs and I changed all of them to async Task functions and awaited those when calling.

2. I have publish the project on AWS Elastic Beanstalk (.NET Core running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/2.4.3) and my project is on .NET 3. This issue came after I changed my project to .NET 6. So, I moved my project to .NET 3 and published it again.

I believe both of these helped my SignalR Hubs to be stable